# What's the Facebook Javascript SDK equivalent of fb:req-choice?

Tags: facebook, social-networking, fbml, facebook-javascript-sdk, invite

I can post an apprequest from my site onto selected friends' walls with a call to `FB.ui`. I'm doing this to replace an old call that goes via some FBML, namely `fb:multi-friend-selector`. What isn't clear from the documentation is how to do the equivalent of `fb:req-choice` using the new API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you could use this from the JS SDK:

```
     function sendRequestToOneRecipient() {
        var user_id = document.getElementsByName("user_id")[0].value;
        FB.ui({method: 'apprequests',
          message: 'My Great Request',
          to: user_id, 
        }, requestCallback);
      }
```